# How to sum all rows from multiple columns

Tags: python

I want to do several operations that are repeated for several columns but I can't do it with a list-comprehension or with a loop.

The dataframe I have is `concern_polls` and I want to rescale the percentages and the total amounts.

```
                                                  text   very  somewhat  \
0    How concerned are you that the coronavirus wil...  19.00     33.00   
1    How concerned are you that the coronavirus wil...  26.00     32.00   
2    Taking into consideration both your risk of co...  13.00     26.00   
3    How concerned are you that the coronavirus wil...  23.00     32.00   
4    How concerned are you that you or someone in y...  11.00     24.00   
..                                                 ...    ...       ...   
625  How worried are you personally about experienc...  33.09     36.55   
626  How do you feel about the possibility that you...  30.00     31.00   
627  Are you concerned, or not concerned about your...  34.00     35.00   
628  Are you personally afraid of contracting the C...  28.00     32.00   
629  Taking into consideration both your risk of co...  22.00     40.00   

     not_very  not_at_all                                                url  
0       23.00       11.00  https://morningconsult.com/wp-content/uploads/...  
1       25.00        7.00  https://morningconsult.com/wp-content/uploads/...  
2       43.00       18.00  https://d25d2506sfb94s.cloudfront.net/cumulus_...  
3       24.00        9.00  https://morningconsult.com/wp-content/uploads/...  
4       33.00       20.00  https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/polls/202...  
..        ...         ...                                                ...  
625     14.92       12.78  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cIEEkz...  
626     14.00       16.00  https://www.washingtonpost.com/context/jan-10-...  
627     19.00       12.00  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1H3uFRD7X0Qttk...  
628     16.00       15.00  https://leger360.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/0...  
629     21.00       16.00  https://docs.cdn.yougov.com/4k61xul7y7/econTab...  

[630 rows x 15 columns]
```

Variables `very`, `somewhat`, `not_very` and `not_at_all` they are represented as percentages of the column `SAMPLE_SIZE`, not shown in the sample share. The percentages don't always add up to 100% so I want to rescale it

To do this, I take the following steps: I calculate the sum of the columns -> variable I `sum` calculate the amount per `%`. This step could leave it as a variable and not create a new column in it `df`. I calculate the final amounts

The code I have so far is this:

```
sums = concern_polls['very'] + concern_polls['somewhat'] + concern_polls['not_very'] + concern_polls['not_at_all']


concern_polls['Very'] = concern_polls['very'] / sums * 100
concern_polls['Somewhat'] = concern_polls['somewhat'] / sums * 100
concern_polls['Not_very'] = concern_polls['not_very'] / sums * 100
concern_polls['Not_at_all'] = concern_polls['not_at_all'] / sums * 100


concern_polls['Total_Very'] = concern_polls['Very'] / 100 * concern_polls['sample_size']
concern_polls['Total_Somewhat'] = concern_polls['Somewhat'] / 100 * concern_polls['sample_size']
concern_polls['Total_Not_very'] = concern_polls['Not_very'] / 100 * concern_polls['sample_size']
concern_polls['Total_Not_at_all'] = concern_polls['Not_at_all'] / 100 * concern_polls['sample_size']
```

I have tried to raise the function with "*list comprehension*" but I can't.

Could someone make me a suggestion?

The problems that I find is that I want to add all the rows of several columns, but they are not all of the `df` doing repetitive operations on several columns, but they are not all of the `df`

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
df[newcolumn] = df.apply(lambda row : function(row), axis=1)
```

is your friend here I think.
"axis=1" means it does it row by row.

As an example :

```
concern_polls['Very'] = concern_polls.apply(lambda row: row['very'] / sums * 100, axis=1)
```

And if you want sums to be the total of each of those df columns it'll be

```
sums = concern_polls[['very', 'somewhat', 'not_very', 'not_at_all']].sum().sum()
```